# How to sort out duplicate entries in terms of value?

Tags: shell

I have the following data

```
36 1 Exp/FXR_36-A     8.11235215439
36 1 Exp/FXR_36-C     8.21811660743
36 2 Exp/FXR_36-A     1.25092447969
36 2 Exp/FXR_36-C     1.30241737955
36 3 Exp/FXR_36-A     7.01407049989
36 3 Exp/FXR_36-C     7.01082158701
36 4 Exp/FXR_36-A     8.51079567125
36 4 Exp/FXR_36-C     8.49081312769
36 5 Exp/FXR_36-A     6.87734616389
36 5 Exp/FXR_36-C     6.88288703699
```

The desires result should be

```
36 1 Exp/FXR_36-A     8.11235215439
36 2 Exp/FXR_36-A     1.25092447969
36 3 Exp/FXR_36-C     7.01082158701
36 4 Exp/FXR_36-C     8.49081312769
36 5 Exp/FXR_36-A     6.87734616389
```

You can see that there are duplicate entries but I want to keep the entries with lowest value in column 4 and print out a new file with correct entries.

I am trying something like but the output is not what I want

```
sort -k2 -k4 tmp.txt | awk '!x[$4]++'
sort -k4 tmp.txt | awk '!x[$4]++'
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Using Python-Pandas is one option.

Comment: and column 4 does not have duplicates in the input you have provided

Comment: Well for 36 5 there are two entries. I want to keep entry whose column 4 value is lowest.

Comment: @SoumendranathBhakat: Did you make an attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: @Inian I thought sort command in bash will work and then I will use excel to sort again but didn't work sort -k4 file | awk '!x[$4]++'

Comment: @SoumendranathBhakat: Update it as part of the question

Comment: @Inian Thanks a lot. I was looking for the keyword unique everywhere. Thanks it is working now.

Comment: @SoumendranathBhakat: Click on the tick-mark near the left of the answer to mark it resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort`/`awk` combination to achieve this, `sort` to sort on the last column and `awk` to filter out duplicates based on column 1 and 2,

```
sort -k4 file | awk '!unique[$1FS$2]++'
36 2 Exp/FXR_36-A     1.25092447969
36 5 Exp/FXR_36-A     6.87734616389
36 3 Exp/FXR_36-C     7.01082158701
36 1 Exp/FXR_36-A     8.11235215439
36 4 Exp/FXR_36-C     8.49081312769
```

and if you are worried about the order `sort` the output again based on the second column,

```
sort -k4 file | awk '!unique[$1FS$2]++' | sort -k2
36 1 Exp/FXR_36-A     8.11235215439
36 2 Exp/FXR_36-A     1.25092447969
36 3 Exp/FXR_36-C     7.01082158701
36 4 Exp/FXR_36-C     8.49081312769
36 5 Exp/FXR_36-A     6.87734616389
```